# remove spaces between paragraphs

Tags: html, css, email

I am trying to remove the space between 2 consecutive paragraphs.

```
<p style="margin:0; padding:0;"> Text </p>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0; ">  more text</p>
```

I am using inline styles because I am trying to create html email. However it does not remove the spaces in Entourage email service.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the spaces between the paragraphs or IN the paragraphs?

Answer (score 3):

If that is the exact code you are using then `padding;0;` should be `padding:0;` in the first paragraph tag.

Comment: And you should put that inline css into a separate file, or at least within a `<style>` tag. Won't solve your problem directly, but makes the world a better place.

Comment: For html emails the style must be inline or it will be stripped out by many email clients such as gmail.

Comment: @GolezTrol: How would a separate CSS file work with sending an HTML email? I was under the impression that it does not, or is not a good idea.